# search term does not work

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to get tweets from twitter,
I want to search for the tweets that has both #sarcasm and American politician in them but when I use the following I get nothing:
"#sarcasm"+"American politician"

Do I do it correctly? can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of the actual call you are making?

Comment: Thank u and sorry for late response, I checked it with other combination and seems that it works so it seems that the above combination of words does not exist in twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked it with other combination and seems that it works so it seems that the above combination of words does not exist in twitter and the way I am doing it is correct